# Time transform in Excel to show midnight as 12:00:00 AM

Tags: excel, datetime-format

[image]How to transform time format "0:00:00" to "12:00:00 AM" time format in excel automatically (because I have a column with many values and transform manually isn't solution)

Comment: Just apply a number format of `hh:mm:ss AM/PM`

Comment: I set a custom format (hh:mm:ss AM/PM), but the display remains the same "0:00:00" - I need "12:00:00 AM"

Comment: Then your data is stored as text, not a real number value. Try using Data - Text to columns on it.

Comment: If I type manually value into cell (cell has format hh:mm:ss AM/PM) value transform from 0:00:00 to 12:00:00 AM as I need, but if I insert value into cell from other cell(I tried text, number, and others formats) (copy-past) ( I choose insert only value) inserted value doesn't transform to cell format

Comment: Did you try Text to columns? Or use a formula like `=A1+0` to force coercion?

Comment: Format transforms only when I  type 0:00:00  or type at the end of the field AM directly, but I need transformation automatically, because I have thousands of values to transform (pic is attached)

Comment: Initially data in text format

Comment: I have solved the problem by using "=A1+0", thank you